# How to get file IFile from file name in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Having file name as string. Ex: Sample.c.
How to get IFile from this?

Comment: You need to know which folder/project it is in. Do you know that?

Comment: @greg-449 : Not aware. Getting the file path as 
C:\Users\runtime-EclipseApplication\Rule_Validate\Sample_Test.h

Is it ipossible to get the IFile form this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a path which is the full path in the file system you can use:

```java
IPath path = new Path("C:\\Users\\runtime-EclipseApplication\\Rule_Validate\\Sample_Test.h");

IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

IFile file = root.getFileForLocation(path);
```

Note: The result may be `null` if the location is not in the workspace.

There are other APIs if you have a path relative to the workspace or a project/folder in the workspace.